# How to speed up my PHP app with Memcached

Tags: php, optimization, memcached

I've been working on a website lately and want to speed up my application.
I want to cache my users' pages but the pages are dynamic like if someone posts a new feed then the homepage is updated with that new feed. If I cache the homepage for one user and a friend of his posts a new feed I want that cache to be expired and the next time he visits the homepage again the application contacts the database and fetches the new feeds and caches it.

I'm using memcache and PHP and MySQL for my DB.
I have a table called `friends`, `feeds` and `users`.

Will it be efficient to cache every user's friends and when that user posts a feed, my app fetches his/her friends and caches a notification with their userid so that when those friends log in the app checks at every page if there is a notification to take action (in this case deleting the homepage in the cache).

Regards,
Resul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Profile your application and locate places where you access data that is expensive to fetch (or calculate). Those places are good places to start with memcached, unless you're doing more writes than reads (where you'd likely have to update the cache more often than you could make use of it).

Caching everything you ever access could well lead to nothing than a quite full memcached that holds mostly data that is rarely accessed (while potentially pushing things out from the cache you actually *should* cache). In many cases you shouldn't use memcached as a 1:1 copy of your database in key-value form.

Comment: Well, in my case I have to fetch the list of friends nearly on every page so that won't be that much of a problem I guess. But on the homepage you're right, it's not that smart to cache the whole page. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Well, how many friends are we talking about? A few thousand? A million? How many joins does the query contain? How many columns appear in the `WHERE` clause? You can build a poor-man's query log with times with a few lines of code (which would be a lighter approach than xdebug, and also can tell you *which* queries take longer than others).

Comment: We are talking about an average of 500 friends per user because I'm limitting it to a 1000 p/u. Right now I have 4 3.6GHZ 8core PC's with 32 GB of ram each. I don't use joins in finding the friends from the table. First I find the friends with `SELECT uid2 FROM friends WHERE uid1=(user_id) AND active=1` and then I go for the 2nd time to the database to retrieve those friends from the `users` table and instantiate the objects.

Comment: Hm, I'd probably have used `SELECT * from users JOIN friends ON friends.uid2 = users.id WHERE friends.uid1 = (user_id) and friends.active = 1`. I doubt the single join is more expensive than two queries. In any case, neither should be a particular performance bottleneck with those numbers (I'm currently trying to optimise a PHP application where we frequently have joins of three or more tables – and that's noticeable). But as noted, profile! In my experience when trying to guess where a performance problem lies you guess wrong in at least 95 % of cases.

Comment: I'm currently working on your suggestion. Logging my queries in a file. I'm using microtime but in some cases it returns numbers like 4.548251352E-5 and I'm not familiar with the time, microtime and fopen functions. Never used them before. And I think I'm lucky that I never liked using the joins and unions although I had to use them in some cases. Anyway, you're right about the guessing theory. Sometimes it's not the way it seems so logging and debugging is the best approach in these cases.

Comment: `microtime(true)` will give you seconds since the script started as a float. So `$start = microtime(true); $mysql_query($queryString); file_put_contents($logfile, $queryString . ' (' . (microtime(true) - $start) . " seconds)\n", FILE_APPEND);` is a poor man's but already useful query log. Just keep in mind that the function returns an absolute point in time – figuring out a time span is your task (the subtraction).

Answer (score 1):

Before you even start server-side optimizations, you should run [ySlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) and try to get an A rating. Take a hard look at you JavaScript too. If you are using jQuery, then getting rid of it would vastly improve the overall performance of site. The front-end optimization usually is much more important.

Next step would be optimizing cleaning up the server-side code. Try testing your SQL queries qith [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html). See if you are missing some indexes. And then do some profiling on PHP side with [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/). See where the bottlenecks are.

**And only then** start messing with caching. As for Memcached, unless your website runs on top of cluster of servers, you do not need it. Hell .. it might even be harmful. If you site is located on single box, you will get much better results with [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php), which, unlike Memcached, is not distributed by nature.

Comment: Thanks, I have read the book called Pro PHP Application Performance and thanks to that I'm aware of the approaches you suggested me but I couldn't find anything about how to efficiently cache with memcached. I guess I'm still gonna have to use Xdebug and see which functions etc. are using the most resources and optimize them. And, yes, I'm going to run my app on a cluster so like you said APC is not the best tool here. :)

Answer (score 0):

Write a class that handles all the DB queries, caches the tables, and does the queries on the cached tables instead your DB. update your cache each time you do an Insert or an update on a Table.